# Show that sigma algebra is closed under countable intersections

Tags: measure-theory

Is it correct to show that a sigma algebra is closed under countable intersections using de Morgan’s Laws?

Comment: You don' need any law. It is true by definition .

Comment: Sorry I meant to write countable intersections. @gae.S.

Comment: Yes, the $\neg\forall x \equiv\exists x\neg$ is a fine approach, perhaps the only one.

Comment: So if I prove that the complement of the union of Ei is equal to the intersection of the complement of Ei and vice verse I have proven that a sigma algebra is closed under countable intersections @Gae.S

Comment: @KaboMurphy That at least depends on the definition, doesn't it? Normally it is not a part of the definition of the concept $\sigma$-algebra and must looked at as a theorem so that a proof is needed.

Comment: @drhab The question has been modified. When I wrote my comment OP had typed union instead on intersection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A_1,A_2,A_3,  .... $ elements of a $ \sigma-$ algebra, then put

$$I:= \bigcap A_i.$$

de Morgan's law gives for the complements

$$I^c= \bigcup A_i^c.$$

Can you proceed ?